# Searchable Database View with Aggregate Nested Tables in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have four tables: families, parents, children, clubs. families have many parents and many children. The children have many clubs memberships.

I would like to create a "[view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-views.html)" for [fast searching names and email addresses](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/implementing-multi-table-full-text-search-with-postgres) that returns the each of the parents and children, names, email address, along with all an array of all the ids that of all the clubs that their children belong.

Here's what I have so far for the query I would like to be in the view:

```
 SELECT
  families.id AS family_id,
  'Child' AS searchable_type,
  concat(children.first_name, ' ',children.last_name) AS term,
  '' AS email,
  array_agg(memberships.club_id) AS clubs
FROM children
INNER JOIN families ON children.family_id = families.id
LEFT JOIN memberships ON children.id = memberships.child_id
GROUP BY families.id, term, email

UNION

SELECT
  families.id AS family_id,
  'Parent' AS searchable_type,
  concat(parents.first_name, ' ',parents.last_name) AS term,
  parents.email AS email,
  array_agg(memberships.club_id) AS clubs

FROM parents
INNER JOIN families ON parents.family_id = families.id
INNER JOIN children ON families.id = children.family_id
LEFT JOIN memberships ON children.id = memberships.child_id
GROUP BY families.id, email, term
```

Question's are:

- How do I get rid of duplicate club_ids for children and parents?
- It's a really slow query. If it is indexed, will the view be
  updated every time a write happens on child or parent?
- Here is the execution plan: http://explain.depesz.com/s/BA9
- Here is a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9c737/2

---

Comment: Regarding the performance: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Playing with this sort of query is a great deal more practical when you post the schema and some sample data, preferably somewhere like http://sqlfiddle.com/ . Also, see the guidance on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info .

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I will think through how to post more info. The EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) returns 70 lines so I will have to figure out a pithy way to include that to make the question useful.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you. I will take a look at sqlfiddle.com. I have never created one before and pared the tables/schema here a bit to make them more readable.

Comment: You can upload the execution plan to this site: http://explain.depesz.com and then link from here

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks explain.depesz.com is new to me. I don't know how to interpret the result, though. I think this has all the info for both selects in it and does not reveal proprietary info: http://explain.depesz.com/s/BA9

Comment: Your biggest problem is, that so many steps (#2, #6, #16) require sorting on disk which is slow. Try to increase the work_mem for that statement until the sorts on disk go away. Most of the retrieval steps do full table scans which could indicate that you need some indexes on the table.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know how to set the work_mem, so I will have to look at that further. All these columns are indexed, but I cannot tell if I am hitting those. For example, index_scans shows as 0 in pgAdmin for first_name and last_name. Comparatively, the index on children for the family_id has thousands of scans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answers I came up with to my initial questions, though I doubt it is the highest performance method:

> - How do I get rid of duplicate club_ids for children and parents?

Insert DISTINCT into the agg_array function

> - It's a really slow query. If it is indexed, will the view be updated every time a write happens on child or parent?

The query is slow. Creating the view is very quick. The view, as I currently understand, really provides a convenient way for doing searches. The view is not a "real" table. I think this is why making sure your are indexing all of the search terms of the view. You are not indexing the view itself.

Also, I ended up moving the email address into its own query so that became a search term as well.

Here was my final [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9c737/5) that I based the view on:

```
SELECT
  families.id AS family_id,
  'Child' AS searchable_type,
  concat(children.first_name, ' ',children.last_name) AS term,
  array_agg(DISTINCT memberships.club_id) AS clubs
FROM children
INNER JOIN families ON children.family_id = families.id
LEFT JOIN memberships ON children.id = memberships.child_id
GROUP BY families.id, term

UNION

SELECT
  families.id AS family_id,
  'Parent' AS searchable_type,
  concat(parents.first_name, ' ',parents.last_name) AS term,
  array_agg(DISTINCT memberships.club_id) AS clubs

FROM parents
INNER JOIN families ON parents.family_id = families.id
INNER JOIN children ON families.id = children.family_id
LEFT JOIN memberships ON children.id = memberships.child_id
GROUP BY families.id, term

UNION

SELECT
  families.id AS family_id,
  'Parent' AS searchable_type,
  email AS term,
  array_agg(DISTINCT memberships.club_id) AS clubs

FROM parents
INNER JOIN families ON parents.family_id = families.id
INNER JOIN children ON families.id = children.family_id
LEFT JOIN memberships ON children.id = memberships.child_id
GROUP BY families.id, term
```